# Different images between MATLAB and ImageMagick

Tags: png, resize, imagemagick, image-processing, interpolation

Hi,
I'm using ImageMagick 7.0.8-64 Q16 for Windows and MATLAB R2019. I'm doing the same operation (resizing with bicubic interpolation method) in both programs.

ImageMagick code:

```
magick start.png -resize 400x200! -interpolate Catrom -quality 100 start_magick_100.png
```

MATLAB code

```
start_matlab = imresize(start, [200 400], "bicubic")
imwrite(start_matlab, "start_matlab.png", "png")
```

Now, the difference is not visible but reading again both images in MATLAB and ImageJ they are a little bit different in terms of pixels count. I mean that the pixel count is the same but summing the image matrix in MATLAB give me a different result.
How can it be possible? Do IM and Matlab could have different functions even for these simple operations?

Comment: What's the relation to graphic design? How do you expect a designer to answer this? Look at the golden ratio? :)

Comment: Sorry for the inappropriate location. Maybe some interpolation knowledge (that I lack) could be useful, but this might not be the right place!

Comment: Try superuser, stackoverflow, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Super-User or Stack Overflow

Comment: I'm not sure you can access to the source code of Matlab, so you can try to perform the same operation with [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). If the result is identical to the one obtained with Matlab, you can read the sources of both Octave and ImageMagick and see where the algorithms differ.

Answer (score 0):

Different algorithms produces different result and both software handle interpolation differently.

Looking at your code gives a hint that you’re using catmull-rom algorithm for bicubic interpolation in image magic. It gives the smooth result but can’t be compared pixel to pixel with a different algorithm (matlab)

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this quickly before it gets closed. The answer is simply:

*Implementation details count.*

So even if the math is the same. Processing might not be the same. Math and images themselves do not have a straight forward enough interpretation. Think:

- How do you do the math in integer arithmetic
- How do you round numbers?
- Do you implement it all in one stage or not?
- Do you process the image numbers in linear space?

  - or do you just do gamma correction.
  - or do you implement a cms?
  - or do you take the numbers at face value?

etc.